# How to have different Teamcity VSBuild Configurations (Debug/Release) for each specific branch?

Tags: msbuild, teamcity, msdeploy

I have a build configuration that does my building and unit testing for all of my branches of my project. I have another configuration that does my deploying. I need the first configuration to do the build with a "Debug" target if its against a "development" environment and a "Release" target against the rest. Is there a way to go about this without having to make different build configurations?

Answer (score 0):

For all the builds I manage here at my job, we always create different build configurations in TeamCity for Debug and Release. I don't know more about your build environment so obviously I can't answer specifically.

You can however reduce almost all the duplication by using templates. Which is nice. Then the only unique information in your debug build is the word 'Debug', and same for your 'Release' build.